# How to write ouput from for-loop to CSV using Facebook Prophet in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, facebook-prophet

I am trying to use a for-loop in Python in combination with Facebook Prophet forecasting, so I will be able to make a forecast for each product that I want to have a forecast for.

The answer given here is almost perfect:
[forecasting values for each category using Prophet in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49237785/forecasting-values-for-each-category-using-prophet-in-python/)

The answer does not include how to write the output from the loop to a CSV in such a way the topic starter posted in the screenshot.

When I try it myself via:

```
df_temp = get_prediction(df2)
print(df_temp)

df_output = pd.DataFrame(list(df_temp.items()))
df_output.to_csv('Tutorial.csv', index=True)
```

I can see the predictions from Prophet. But since it's in a dictionary output, I don't know how to properly get it into a csv. Storing it in a dataframe also doesn't solve things with pd.DataFrame.from_dict.

Any other ideas for this? Usually I can figure stuff out thanks to stackoverflow, but now I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

I think you need to set `mode=a` in your code to append your prediction into `csv` file.

```
df_output.to_csv('Tutorial.csv', index=True,mode='a')
```

Refer to [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) for more information.